# How do I import modules in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I keep getting module not found errors whenever I try to import modules.
For some reason `import {} from 'angular2/core'` works fine but importing any other module doesn't work.

I'm trying to `import * as Crypto from 'crypto-browserify'` which is located in node_modules. I tried setting up the path in System.Config to point the path to the correct directory, but then all the modules that crypto-browserify references can't be found unless I manually include them in the path also. How do I set it up so it looks for the module A in `/node_modules/A`?

Comment: If you look at the code for that package they don't export much.... Only a couple of functions.

https://github.com/crypto-browserify/crypto-browserify/blob/master/index.js

Comment: yeah, but my question is a bit more general. I've been trying to use crypto-js also. I don't really understand how typescript look up where the type definitions and the modules are located, it seems magical.

Comment: For example, I have installed crypto-js which is located in `/node_modules/crypto_js` and also the type definitions `/types/crypto-js/crypto-js.d.ts`. Problem is if I write `import * as Crypto from 'crypto-js'` it says module not found. If I hardcode the path `import crypto = require('/node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js')` then it works but doesn't find the type definitions so I have no intellisense.

Answer (score 2):

So I got it working on my end.
You have to include it in your HTML

```
<script src="wwwroot/lib/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"></script>
```

Then you have to add the reference to the TSD in your TS file

```
/// <reference path="../tsd/crypto-js/cryptojs.d.ts" />
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/crypto-js/crypto-js.d.ts
```

and in your code you can refernce it through the global variable it exports.

```
CryptoJS.
```

Comment: Could you share a plnkr and the .d.ts file that you have used. In my typescript source file, I did the following:  `let CryptoJS = window["CryptoJS"];` then  `let sha1 = CryptoJS.SHA1(my_string);`. No intellisense though!

Comment: You don't have to do Window["CryptoJS"];
It's a global variable exposed by just CryptoJS.
The intellisense comes from the TSD which I added to my answer.

Comment: I have added the d.ts file, so I have intellisense. I use the global variable `Crypto` but I have an error during transpilation: `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CryptoJS'`. The javascript executes fine. So one mystery remains to be solved: how the global name `CryptoJS` can be known to typescript ?

Comment: Last minute: when I add `declare var CryptoJS` in my typescript source file, the `TS2304` warning disappeared. But the intellisense is also gone. This drives me crazy!!